# How to find eclipse workbench.xmi file on ubuntu?

Tags: eclipse

I'm using a Ubuntu 12.04 VM with eclipse JUNO installed and it stoped working. I restarted the VM and tried to restart eclipse, but it stops working on the initialization.

After doing a search, I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12045547 telling me to remove workbench.xmi file. The problem is that I have no idea how can I find it, and guys who setup this VM are on other continent, so I didn't want to wait 5h until they go to work to help me..
Could you please guide me to find it please?

Comment: Starting Eclipse with the '-clearPersistedState' option is a more controlled way of deleting the workbench.xmi file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is in your home folder, eg.:

```
~/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi
```

You can search it with this command.

```
find ~/workspace -type f -name "workbench.xmi"
```

I'm using `~/workspace`, because that is the default path.

Alternatively, you can also use this command, but it takes a while.

```
find ~ -type f -name "workbench.xmi"
```

Comment: when I run ~/workspace -name "workbench.xmi" it just says :" Workspace is a diretory

Comment: run `find ~/workspace -name "workbench.xmi"`, as I wrote it.

Comment: if I go to the workspace folder via UI, isn't there any way I could see this workbench.xmi file visually and remove it from the folder (without deleting it, just for testing purposes?)

Comment: ok, so when I run it, nothing happens.. no return messages.. what should I expect as a result? folder being opened? something on the terminal?

Comment: Is there the folder "workspace"?

Comment: yes, there is..

Comment: Then go into this folder: `cd ~/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/`

Comment: it says: "no such file or directory"

Comment: Ok, let's try this: `find ~ -type f -name "workbench.xmi"`

Comment: now it worked! /workspace1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi

Comment: give me a vote and flag the answer :)

Comment: the vote I had already given ;) now thanks for the help!

Comment: Sometimes it takes a while to find the correct answer!  ;-)